# How to loop through Names collection and return size of objects?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through the Names collection, and each Name that fits a certain size (column) requirement gets resized (called in a different sub).

When I try to pass the names returned to a Range I get below error.

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed.

```
Sub colCounts()
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim nm as Name
    Dim rng as Range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each nm in wb.Names
        debug.print nm.Name ' verify loop returning as expected
        Set rng = Range(nm.Name) 'this line throws the error when added
        debug.print nm.Name & " " & rng.Columns.Count
    Next nm
End Sub
```

I also tried passing the Name to a string first:

```
Dim str as String
.....
str = nm.Name
Set rng = Range(str)
```

Comment: It's `nm.Name` not `nm.Names` but you should use `nm.Referstorange` instead, after making sure it actually refers to a range.

Comment: Thanks, typo on my end when putting the code in the post (edited).  It is nm.Name in the sub.  Can you elaborate on how to implement? `Set rng = nm.RefersToRange`?  If I try it in the loop I still get error '1004'

Comment: As I said, you need to ensure that the name actually refers to a range. It might not.

Comment: Thanks Rory.  Turns out the error was being thrown by a hidden "_xlfn.IFERROR" range.  There was an IFERROR buried in the workbook; deleting that, unhiding and deleting the named range fixed it.

Updated to `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Names(nm.Name).RefersToRange` and everything works as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: That's a very roundabout way to get to `Set rng = nm.RefersToRange` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub colCounts()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim rng As range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

   For Each nm In wb.Names

       Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Names(nm.Name).RefersToRange
       Debug.Print nm.Name & " " & rng.Columns.Count

    Next nm

End Sub
```